# Mootools getComputedSize not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, mootools, mootools-more

I am using the Mootools More function "getComputedSize" on a dynamically created DIV element. It works fine in Firefox but not in Google Chrome:

CSS:

```
.resultBox {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
this.resultBox = new Element('div', {
    'class': 'resultBox'
});

console.log(this.resultBox.getComputedSize().width);
```

The result is "150" in FF but in Chrome the result is "NaN".

Does anyone know how to fix this in Chrome without having to code the DIV into the html ?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Fixed:

```
this.resultBox = new Element('div', {
    'class': 'resultBox'
});

this.resultBox.inject(this.container, 'top');

console.log(this.resultBox.getComputedSize().width);
```

Inject the element before trying to use this method.

Comment: it needs to be injected into the dom first.

Comment: FYI at the end of the call stack, `.width` will get populated by a call to `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this.resultBox, null).width`. Since the element you are trying to compute styles for is not in the DOM tree, `getComputedStyle` returns the empty string in Chrome and I think Opera, while Firefox computes it as asked. The spec is a little vague on what implementations are suppose to do in this case. See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2010Apr/0433.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I injected it into the DOM earlier than I was doing originally and now it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
this.resultBox = new Element('div', {
    'class': 'resultBox'
});

this.resultBox.inject(this.container, 'top');

console.log(this.resultBox.getComputedSize().width);
```

Inject the element before trying to use this method.